# Is there any difference between variant() and variant?

Tags: excel, vba

Consider

```
Dim u As Variant, v() As Variant

u = Range("A1:B3").Value
v = Range("A1:B3").Value
```

Is there now any difference between u and v? And if not, is it superfluous to declare v as a variant array as opposed to declaring it simply as a variant?

Comment: I don't see any benefit in declaring it as an array of Variants.

Comment: You can make an argument that adding the () is useful in that it signals *intent* regarding the usage of v, which is helpful to someone else reading your code (or to you, later on)

Comment: One disadvantage I found of adding the () is that it causes an error when attempting to assign an empty array to it. For example if some function returns an array but the array is empty then v = SomeFunction() will cause a run-time error but u = SomeFunction() will not.

Answer (score 3):

There are differences. Think of a `Variant` as being something that exists at a low level on your machine and has an application programming interface (API) to VBA. That low level thing is a `VARIANT` and Windows ships with several functions that allow you to manipulate it in many languages; VBA being one of them.

`v` is a Visual Basic array of such `VARIANT`s, `u` is a single one.

One way of spotting the difference is to use `VarType(v)` which evaluates to `vbArray + vbVariant`. `VarType(u)` evaluates to `vbEmpty`. You can test this prior to assignment to the range contents.

In your specific case, Excel-VBA is doing something funky (I don't think there is any other term) when assigning to `v`: it "knows" that the destination type is an array and performs a slightly different coercion. `u` and `v` are exactly the same having been set to the value of an `Excel.Range`.

Comment: Unless you pick a single cell with `Range()` where assignment to `v` is going to fail.

Comment: Both evaluate to `vbVariant+vbArray` for me, unless a single cell is selected which evaluates to `vbDouble` if it contains a number.